# PHP: How to duplicate the first count of loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a fecth while loop and i need to duplicate the first count 1.

```
$count=1;
while($soc_sql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
   echo'<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="'.$count.'"></span>';
$count++;
}
//this output is
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="1"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="2"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="3"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="4"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="5"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="6"></span>
```

I need the output of this

```
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="1"></span> //<--How do i duplicate
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="1"></span> //<--this first count 1
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="2"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="3"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="4"></span>
<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="5"></span>
```

Comment: HTML IDs have to be unique. Duplicates result into a HTML specification violation.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$count` value and repeat output:

```
$count=1;
while($soc_sql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
    echo'<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="'.$count.'"></span>';
    if ($count == 1) {
        echo'<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="'.$count.'"></span>';
    }

    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First time create first row outside of loop, then iterate loop and create rest.

```
$count=1;
echo '<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="'.$count.'"></span>';
while($soc_sql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
   echo '<span class="icon_remove_sub" id="'.$count.'"></span>';
$count++;
}
```